# Access file from multiple threads application/-s

Tags: vb.net

I change my application to multi thread app. When i made multithreading i have problem with reading my file since one or many applications trying to read file from multiple threads i am getting error that `Process cannot read the file because it's being use by another process.`

This is my class i use to read file:

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.IO

Public Class EmailSerializer
    Public EmailConfig As New EmailConfig
    Private ReadOnly _configPath As String = String.Empty

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(configPath As String)
        _configPath = configPath
    End Sub

    Public Sub Add(emailConfig As EmailConfig)
        Me.EmailConfig = emailConfig
    End Sub

    Public Function GetEmail() As EmailConfig
        Return EmailConfig
    End Function

    Public Function GetSmtPip() As String
        Return EmailConfig.Smtpip
    End Function

    Public Function Load(configPath As String) As EmailSerializer
        Dim result As EmailSerializer
        Dim streamReaderInstance As StreamReader
        If (File.Exists(configPath)) Then
        streamReaderInstance = New StreamReader(configPath)
        End If

        Dim xmlSerializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(EmailSerializer))
        Dim stringReader As New StringReader(streamReaderInstance.ReadToEnd())
        result = DirectCast(xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader), EmailSerializer)
        stringReader.Close()
        streamReaderInstance.Close()
        EmailConfig = result.EmailConfig
        Return result
    End Function

End Class
```

This how i read file:

```
_emailSerializer = New EmailSerializer().Load(configEmail)
_emailSerializer.GetEmail()
```

Error occurs on first line.

What to change to not getting such error?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to create the StreamReader so that it uses read-only access for the file. Then multiple threads should be able to read it.

```
streamReaderInstance = New StreamReader(File.OpenRead(configPath))
```

Comment: will it work also for diffrent same application instances access to that file?

Comment: I believe it will work for separate processes as well as threads.

Comment: unfortunetly not.